# Remove underlined hyperlink from the Wordpress WYSIWYG editor

Tags: angular, wordpress, hyperlink, wysiwyg, underline

In my application I am using Wordpress as CMS. I retrieved data from the wordpress using angular. In CMS I used WYSIWYG editor and try to display those values within angular page. Everything works fine except underlined hyperlinks.
In angular application all the hyperlinks are underlined. I used below code in css file in angular component. But it is not going to work.

`text-decoration : none;`

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.